# pointer to struct in C

Tags: c, string, pointers, structure, c-strings

I'm learning pointer to structure in c and i've made this code for learning :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct
{
   int id;
   char *name;
}struct_type_t;

void set_struct(struct_type_t **);

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
     struct_type_t *m = NULL;

     set_struct(&m);

     printf("%d\n", m->id);
     //fflush(stdout);
     printf("%s\n", m->name);
     return 0;
 }

 void set_struct(struct_type_t **m)
 {
      struct_type_t t;
      *m = &t;

      (*m)->id = 5;
      (*m)->name = "Pointer To Structure";
 }
```

The function `set_struct` is meant to set the struct members by passing the address of pointer to structure `struct_type *m` to the function.

but in the printf line in the main function, it's not print the string member `name` of structure, instead it only print the integer member `id`.

I have used fflush to, but still not working.

please help me to correct this code and check what's wrong....

Answer (score 0):

You return pointer to local object. It's created on stack. You shouldn't use it after function finishes its work because it doesn't exist anymore and its memory may contain other objects.

Allocate chunk of memory on heap using `malloc`, initialize it and use it until you call `free` on it.

Answer (score 0):

Your `*m` is a pointer and is equal to `NULL`. So use malloc to have a pointer to your `struct_type_t` that you can free it after.

```
void set_struct(struct_type_t **m)
{
    *m = (struct_type_t *)malloc(sizeof(struct_type_t));
    (*m)->id = 5;
    (*m)->name = strdup("Pointer To Structure");
    // or: (*m)->name = "Pointer To Structure";
}
```

Comment: @harianja which is undefined behavior because that object goes out of scope

Comment: @CoffeeandCode if it goes out of scope, then why it still print the id member of the struct?

Comment: @harianja *Undefined* behavior. Hide ya wife and hide ya kids, cause **anything** could happend.